# Using Split Orders Extension but order confirmation mail is shooting for first order only instead of all

Tags: event-observer, order-email, magento2.2.4, marketplace, order-splitting

I'm **using "order split" extension** based on seller,means if there are 6 items in the cart having 3 different seller(have 2 item for each seller) then three orders(let's says order id as 500,501,502) are creating.

Then **email is shooting only for order id 500(may be magento default function is calling to shoot only one  email) but i want to shoot email for each order.**

It seems there is some problem in the extesnion.they have used an event and  which is not able to shoot email for each order but i'm getting all the order_id here.i tried to shoot email using this order id but it didn't work.

Extension is purchased but support team didn't support.

So please help me to resolve this issue as this issue is very urgent.

Comment: You need to do the code to send the email where they write the logic to seprate the order.